# How to stretch a pixmap to the edge of the window?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qpixmap, qvboxlayout

I have a PyQt window. The window is made up of a VBoxLayout within a HBoxLayout and is displayed below.

This is what the window currently looks like:

[image]

However, I want the image to stretch to the edge of the window like in the edited image below:

[image]

I have tried setting the `padding` and `contentsmargin` of the window to zero but this messses up the spacing in the rest of the HBoxLayout. Is there any way to stretch this image to fill the window edges without messing up the spacing in the rest of my layout.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.CentralWidget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.CentralWidget)
    self.VBL1 = QVBoxLayout()

    LogoLabel = QLabel()
    LogoPixmap = QPixmap("Resources/Logo.png").scaledToHeight(30)
    LogoLabel.setPixmap(LogoPixmap)
    LogoLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.VBL1.addWidget(LogoLabel)

    self.WelcomeLabel = QLabel("Welcome Back!")
    self.VBL1.addWidget(self.WelcomeLabel)

    UsernameLabel = QLabel("Username")
    self.VBL1.addWidget(UsernameLabel)

    self.UsernameTB = QLineEdit()
    self.VBL1.addWidget(self.UsernameTB)

    PasswordLabel = QLabel("Password")
    self.VBL1.addWidget(PasswordLabel)

    self.PasswordTB = QLineEdit()
    self.VBL1.addWidget(self.PasswordTB)

    self.SignInBTN = QPushButton("Sign In")
    self.VBL1.addWidget(self.SignInBTN)

    self.CreateAccountBTN = QPushButton("Create An Account")
    self.VBL1.addWidget(self.CreateAccountBTN)

    # Art Label stores the image I want to stretch to the edges
    ArtLabel = QLabel()
    ArtPixmap = QPixmap("Stylesheet/LoginArt.jpg").scaledToHeight(250)
    ArtLabel.setPixmap(ArtPixmap)

    self.HBL1 = QHBoxLayout()
    self.HBL1.addLayout(self.VBL1)
    self.HBL1.addWidget(ArtLabel)
    self.CentralWidget.setLayout(self.HBL1)
```

Comment: Use `self.HBL1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`. If doing this leaves you with too small space around the widgets on the left, set the desired space with `self.VBL1.setContentsMargins(22, 22, 22, 22)`.

Comment: I have already tried doing that, however it also affects the contents margins of all the other widgets in that layout. I need to stretch the image out to the edge of the window without affecting the spacing of everything else in my layout

Comment: I have edited my comment.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to preserve the spacing between the image and the widgets, specify a different value for the right margin of the `VBL1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! that works perfectly

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.HBL1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

If doing this leaves you with too small space around the widgets on the left, set the desired space with `self.VBL1.setContentsMargins(22, 22, 22, 22)`.

Additionally, if you want to preserve the spacing between the image and the widgets, specify a different value for the right margin of the `VBL1`.